# Why are these string not equal?

Tags: java

I am reading a String from a file and comparing it to content that I know to be in the file

Here is the relevant code

Test.java

```
@Test
    public void testReadFile() throws IOException {
        String expectedFileContent = "##########\n#A...#...#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#.#....#B#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#....#...#\n##########";
        System.out.println(expectedFileContent);
        String readFile = readFile("test/maze1.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(readFile);
        System.out.println(expectedFileContent.equalsIgnoreCase(readFile));
        assertEquals(readFile, expectedFileContent);
    }
```

readFile.Java

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException
    {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
```

mae1.txt

```
##########
#A...#...#
#.#.##.#.#
#.#.##.#.#
#.#....#B#
#.#.##.#.#
#....#...#
##########
```

When I run the test the test fails however when I compare the string visually they are the same.

Is there a way to make this test pass?

Comment: Compare character by character (with a loop) to find out where they differ.  It's probably down to some difference in encoding or invisible/whitespace characters.

Comment: Have you checked whether you are using same line separators in the file as in your code?

Comment: Most probably mismatching line-endings.

Comment: My first guess would be checking line separators. Windows is using `\r\n`, but your string contains only `\n`.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse: Open the JUnit tab when you run the test and it should show you where the strings differ using a bracket notation: i.e., the two strings "hello" and "Hello" would output a difference like "[H]ello" on the JUnit output tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code when invoke length() method, your expectedContentFile has **87** characters but your string from file is **88**, and then I invoke **trim()** on the string from file and then both are equal.

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import java.io.IOException;

```
public class ReadFile{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
        String expectedFileContent = "##########\n#A...#...#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#.#....#B#\n#.#.##.#.#\n#....#...#\n##########";

        System.out.println(expectedFileContent);
        System.out.println(expectedFileContent.length());

        String x = readFile("file.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
        System.out.println(x.length());
        if(expectedFileContent.equals(x.trim())){
            System.out.println("equal");
        }else{
            System.out.println("not equal");
        }
}
    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException{
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }
}
```

Eidt(Debugging):

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    String x =  new String(encoded, encoding);
    int count = 0;
    for(char ch: x.toCharArray()){
        System.out.println(ch + " " + ++count );
    }
    return x;
}
```

The output(Just post the last 10 characters, format is `character counter`) is:

```
# 78
# 79
# 80
# 81
# 82
# 83
# 84
# 85
# 86
# 87

 88
```

You can see there's one more character at the end and it is the extra

Comment: that is not an answer

Comment: @TimCastelijns please see my edit

Comment: This is working but should not be accepted as an answer as we are trimming the contents. The comparison should be done by considering the originality of the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows you don't have the same ending line by default (\r\n), so you have to arrange your string or convert your file.

Comment: I am on Windows, how can I convert it to use \n

Comment: It might be easier to change your expected file content string

Comment: But this may have to run on unix also. Does that matter?

Comment: If you use Notepad++, you can go on the menu "Edit" then EOL conversion and unix format

Comment: If you have to run it on unix then it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps after you reading file you have whitespaces in the end of the string, remove them by `yourStringFromFile.trim()` method and all will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the file you are reading has (\r\n) like windows uses, try using this

```
String readFile = readFile("test/maze1.txt", Charset.defaultCharset());
readFile = readFile.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "\n");
```

This will normalize the file according to your string

Answer (score 0):

"\r\n" get appended to the file content by default. You can use Files.readAllLines and join all the string by \n. Here is the code:

```
static String readFile(String path) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        return String.join("\n",strings);
    }
```

Comment: @John Hamlett IV have you checked this approach?